# How to reply to a status update for a job application?

Tags: formality, email

I received an email today telling me that I will be notified about next steps for my job application by mid next week. I want to be polite and respond something brief, but since I'm not a native English speaker, I often have trouble with simple greetings and formalities. So far I've come up with this, but I think it sounds a bit awkward and redundant:

> Thank you for keeping me up to date. I will be looking forward to hearing about the status of my application.

What do you think? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Instead of “I will be looking forward to” write “I look forward to”

Comment: Before replying, check whether this is an automated message.  They may not expect any response at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an excellent answer: brief, but polite.

There is, however, a small grammar mistake. Even though you're talking about a future event, *look forward to* describes how you feel **now**, so you should use the present tense:

> I **look forward to** hearing about the status of my application.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could also say "Thanks for the opportunity to interview with your company....(add the rest here). Also you could ask if there was anything else they needed from you for the next steps.

Answer (score 1):

To be very brief, polite and precise, you can use 
Thank you for the update. I look forward to hear about the status of my application.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

> Dear (add name of the person),
>
> Thank you for the update; it is greatly appreciated.
>
> I will look forward to hearing from you accordingly.
>
> With best regards

Answer (score -1):

I really appreciate you for considering my application. I look forward to hearing about the status of my application.

Best Regards

Comment: The other answers to the question don't make this clear but ELU isn't a letter-writing service. Good answers should explain why the suggested phrasing is better than the alternatives and what nuances it conveys.